# When declaring my second method in c# i get the error "Static local functions is not available in c# 7.3"

Tags: c#

when i declared my first method

```
static void Generation()
{
}
```

it works perfectly fine but when i try to declare my second method using the same code

```
static void Rendering()
{
}
```

it get the error "Static local functions is not available in c# 7.3". i read that i can be fixed by writing

```
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
```

but i want to know why it works the first time and not the second.

Comment: You are trying to declare the second function inside the first one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have which shows that the declaration of `Generation()` is working, but the declaration of `Rendering()` is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your syntax, expecially with the order of braces `{}` etc...

It seems the compiler believes the second function is somehow inside the first one.

Error (in C# < 7.3)

```
static void Generation()
{
static void Rendering()
{
}
}
```

Correct:

```
static void Generation()
{
}
static void Rendering()
{
}
```

Note that **many syntax errors inside the body of the first function** could confuse the compiler, and make it believe that the first function has not been ended before the second. For instance, I'd suggest to double-check all pairs of `()` or `{}` or `[]`, and terminating `;`.

When using C# 8, (or 7.3) it's not an error anymore because you can actually define `static` functions inside others, but as far as I understand your question, that's not what you intended to do.